# How to train the left hand (Piano)

Tags: piano, technique

So, how can I go about working on my left hand on the piano?

I can play relatively fast passages with it, but the hand feels weak even if the overall thing sounds fine, also, if one of my two hands goes out, or becomes uneven in any way, it is almost always my left. It's kinda funny because my left hand used to be the strongest as I am left-handed, but, as I've advanced, my right hand is now exceptionally strong because most of the pieces I play require an active right hand and an accompanying left hand.

Comment: The only answer is practice or get a good teacher.

Comment: If you give some idea of the level of repertoire that is causing trouble, more specific suggestions could be made.

Comment: All forms of scales in rapid tempi give me the most trouble, but also sections such as bar 8 of Mozart's sonata k 284 where the left-hand doubles the melody, or in passages where the left hand is the melody played in 16th notes.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you've probably sick of hearing this but - practice! It's the quickest way to get better. Really, the only way to get better. As for *what* to practice, do you have a teacher? There are etude books (Hanon, Czerny, Moskowski) that target not only the left hand but many 'weak' fingers as well! You can ask your teacher to help you with this and perhaps choose pieces with left-hand melodies?

The way you play is also a big factor. Remember to dig into the keys to get a full sound, even during softer passages, and make sure you are playing with the fingertips. It is much harder to play quickly with flat fingers than it is to play quickly with the fingertips. Regarding the specific piece of music, if you are struggling with the left hand try to play it slowly at first, then pick up the speed. This is also true for anything you have trouble with in general.

Remember, playing the piano is like playing a sport.  Michael Phelps didn't learn how to swim overnight. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend finding a piece with a challenging left hand part and focusing on it, such as the revolutionary etude by Chopin. Maybe even a left hand only piece (a Scriabin etude?) would help.

If those pieces are too hard I guess there’s really no other option than just practicing left hand alone a lot and doing scales.

Maybe see this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/piano/comments/5mdq5z/left_hand_exercises_to_improve_dexterity/

Answer (score 0):

Playing the piano with the left hand is weird to start with. To train the left hand, you need a *lot* of practice. Things that can improve your left hand's strength while playing include:

- Trying piano exercises that train the left hand so that it feels stronger while playing.

--OR--

- Consulting with a piano teacher or someone who is experienced in playing the piano and ask them how they train their left hand.

Since you are having more trouble playing the left hand as an accompaniment, try playing the left hand by itself before playing the right hand. You could play the left hand faster and faster until your hand and fingers are used to the movements required. Then you can add the right hand.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Either start learning some Etudes that have a focus in building hand strength, there's a lot of them.
2. Another is to practice all of your scales, then do them in odd patterns, so instead of going: `C D E F G A B C`, go `C D E D E F E F G F G A G A B A B C`, and start doing them faster and faster; plus just playing pieces with challenging left hand parts.

A pianist that I like has some pieces with challenging left hand parts, his name is David Hicken, check him out. Hope this helps.